# HTML5 Multiple Canvases event listener - how to determine which canvas experienced the event?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, addeventlistener, mouseclick-event

I'm new to JS. I'm not using jQuery, and I have a question. I've created a variable number of canvases on a page, all have an eventlistener like so:

```
            for (i=0; i<numberOfCanvases; i++){
                var canv =  document.createElement("canvas");
                canv.addEventListener('click', clickReporter, false);
                document.body.appendChild(canv); }
```

Given the listener function clickReporter:

```
        function clickReporter(e){...}
```

I am trying to use this function to tell me the mouse position of the click event relative to the canvas:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt){
// get canvas position
var obj = canvas;
var top = 0;
var left = 0;
while (obj && obj.tagName != 'BODY') {
    top += obj.offsetTop;
    left += obj.offsetLeft;
    obj = obj.offsetParent;
}
// return relative mouse position
var mouseX = evt.clientX - left + window.pageXOffset;
var mouseY = evt.clientY - top + window.pageYOffset;
return {
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY
};
```

}

which i found from this tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

The problem is, it assumes there is only one canvas, and I do have a list of canvases right now that are placed on a webpage, but I was wondering, given just the clickReporter() function, is there an easy way to determine which canvas was selected? a function like evt.getCanvas() or evt.getParentCanvas()?

I'm asking because when an event occurs (a mouse click on 1 of many canvases, I want to create actions at that location for ONLY that canvas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function clickReporter(e){
    console.log( this ); // in a eventListener , this point to the element fire the event
    console.log( e.target ); // in fireFox and webkit, e.target point to the element fire the event
}
```

Comment: I ended up using 'this' keyword. Is there any difference between e.target and 'this'? thanks!

Comment: '''e.target''' means a proper on a Event Object, then '''this''' is in function's context,refer to the element you bind the handle, in this case they're point to a same obj; in another condition, may not

Answer (score 1):

I would think evt.target ([event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target)) would work.