# JavaScript click event on drawn image in canvas coordinates get

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas rectangle element which i draw on it. I searched a lot about taking coordinates but couldn't understand quite lot. I mean i want to add EventListener to it
but it is not a DOM element so, I'm asking how can i add EventListener on given coordinates of the canvas? Here is my code:

```
function test() {
   var c = document.getElementById("field");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.rect(230,100,150,50);
   ctx.stroke();
   ??.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      funcTest();
   }, false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a onMouseMove event listener to your `<canvas>` element, then with a `position` set to `relative` :

```
function mouseMoved(e)
{
    var mouseX, mouseY;

    if(e.offsetX) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    }
    else if(e.layerX) {
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }

 //do wxhatever you want with the coordinates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.target`.

```
This property of event objects is the object the event was dispatched on. It is different than event.currentTarget when the event handler is called in bubbling or capturing phase of the event.
```

I recommend you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508357/html5-multiple-canvases-event-listener-how-to-determine-which-canvas-experienc) link to refer to.

Comment: Could you be more specific about this event.target ? and how to use it

Comment: It is   the DOM interface implemented by objects that can receive DOM events and have listeners for them.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas's don't work quite like that, they are literally a collection of pixels. You can approximate what you want by adding a listener to the canvas as a whole then checking the co-ord's of the click.

```
c.addEventListner('click',function(event){
    var point = getPos(event);//psuedo function
    if(point.x > 230 && point.y > 100 && point.x < 380 && point.y < 150)
       console.log("rectangle clicked");

},false);
```

You could automate this check for multiple objects obviously, and use stored values for the rectangle instead of hardcoded values but that should get you started.